# Client-side validation framework for Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js, client-side-validation, rich-client-platform

I am developing a rich client web application and wondering whether which framework would be suitable for client-side validations. I tried JQuery validations plugin but found out it does not really works well with knockout `data-bind="click: saveData"` binding.

Is there any specific client-side validation framework for knockout.js?

Any idea is appreciated.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is a validation framework specifically built for KO: https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation